# Mysql delete in one table by id's from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
A
id | name
```

and

```
B
id | name
```

On B table i create query to select all data, where id's are in (... some values), but how can i in one query select this B - id's and delete from A where A.id = B.id ?

I'm new to sql.... Could not find how to combine all in one query...

*i must select from b on some like query, for example my b query: select * from B where somefieldinteger in (1,4,9,21,25) and that b.id must compare with a*

**upd**
this throw error

```
delete `LINK_LA_TYP` FROM `LINK_LA_TYP` JOIN `LINK_ART` ON `LINK_LA_TYP`.LAT_LA_ID=`LINK_ART`.LA_ID JOIN `ARTICLES` ON `LINK_ART`.LA_ART_ID=`ARTICLES`.ART_ID WHERE (`ARTICLES`.ART_SUP_ID in (10008,10439,11005,10097,10669,11100,80,10912,10683,10675,10194,11196,1166,10730,10248,10870,11200,11059,247,10121,10911,489,10724,496,10093,10205,1318,10953,11199,11047,128,114,194,10865,11058,10345,1286,10667,10064,11077,10622,11205,10917,10344,495,10709,10954,10744,304,10957,10447,10764,10129,10862,10918,10731,11115,10095,10859,10580,1345,10177,10323,144,11182,10132,256,10941,58,10006,10017,10780,10765,10665,11110,10714,10224,750,10267,10179,10725,10774,11063,10868,10103,10676,10057,10649,255,10322,11022,309,10754,11121,10801,10018,11004,10245,146,11056,381,10781,10699,11120,11126,830,10240,11162,10436,10584,10342,10861,11190,10721,11171,10564,10545,94,10087,73,10755,10869,10547,10706,10346,444,426,10059,153,122,10674,64,113,11101,10231,10337,806,11117,10385,251,11188,491,11192,100,10792,10069,10864,11099,10246,10178,10758,10568,10230,10124,10384,10782,10726,384,10670,305,10763,10768,10585,10394,10552,498,10677,1348,168,10814,10582,10382,11093,11173,10381,427,441)) limit 50
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `delete` together with `join` like this:

```
mysql> create table a (id int);
mysql> insert into a values (1), (2), (3), (4);
mysql> create table b (id int);
mysql> insert into b values (2), (3);
mysql> delete a from a join b on a.id=b.id where b.id > 2;
mysql> select * from a;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

This scales to arbitrary number of tables, e.g.:

```
DELETE a 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.idA=b.idA 
JOIN c ON b.idB=c.idB;
```

This will delete from `a` all records that are referred from those records of `b` which are in turn referred from `c`.  You may also add WHERE clause like this:

```
DELETE a 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.idA=b.idA 
JOIN c ON b.idB=c.idB
WHERE a.status='done' AND
      b.status='open' AND
      c.status='open';
```

If you want to limit number of rows to be deleted, do like this:

```
DELETE a 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.idA=b.idA 
JOIN c ON b.idB=c.idB
LIMIT 500000;
```

If you want to delete first 500000 rows, you need to refine which rows are first, so you need to establish some ordering among rows.  In other words you need to sort rows by some criteria and then limit like this:

```
DELETE a 
FROM a 
JOIN b ON a.idA=b.idA 
JOIN c ON b.idB=c.idB
ORDER BY a.something
LIMIT 500000;
```

Comment: this tables haven't relations

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris What do you mean by relations?  In my example there is not explicit relations between `a` and `b`.

Comment: note! a.id = b.id is good, but first i must select from b on some like query, for example my b query: select * from B where somefieldinteger in (1,4,9,21,25)   and that b.id must compare with a

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris Added part how to do this

Comment: why b.id > 2 ?  maybe chat... .russian ?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris Add anything you like after `where`, `b.id in (2, 4, 6)` for example.

Comment: Sorry.... But how can i do this for three tables at once? first select B in(...) then select depending on B results A, and then depending on rows given by A, delete from C table (structure is same....) Just B->A->C

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris Added example for deleting from `a` when `c->b->a` and also something about using `WHERE` clause.

Comment: sorry for my newbie questions.... but how can i limit that only first 500 000 entries are deleted in A table?

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris Added example how to limit number of rows to be deleted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033881/mysql-delete-with-join-and-limit/15033927#15033927

Comment: Why do you ignore me? Ideas with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033881/mysql-delete-with-join-and-limit/15033927#15033927  ?

Comment: why do you ignore me ? ((((((((

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from A where exists (select 1 from B where A.id=B.id and B.criteria=true)
```

If you leave out ... and B.criteria=true it would delete all rows in A that appear in B; otherwise you delete whatever matches your criteria.