# Mysql delete with join and limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
DELETE `LINK_LA_TYP` 
FROM `LINK_LA_TYP` 
JOIN `LINK_ART` ON `LINK_LA_TYP`.LAT_LA_ID = `LINK_ART`.LA_ID 
JOIN `ARTICLES` ON `LINK_ART`.LA_ART_ID = `ARTICLES`.ART_ID 
WHERE (`ARTICLES`.ART_SUP_ID in (10008,10439,11005,10097,10669,11100,80,10912,10683,10675,10194,11196,1166,10730,10248,10870,11200,11059,247,10121,10911,489,10724,496,10093,10205,1318,10953,11199,11047,128,114,194,10865,11058,10345,1286,10667,10064,11077,10622,11205,10917,10344,495,10709,10954,10744,304,10957,10447,10764,10129,10862,10918,10731,11115,10095,10859,10580,1345,10177,10323,144,11182,10132,256,10941,58,10006,10017,10780,10765,10665,11110,10714,10224,750,10267,10179,10725,10774,11063,10868,10103,10676,10057,10649,255,10322,11022,309,10754,11121,10801,10018,11004,10245,146,11056,381,10781,10699,11120,11126,830,10240,11162,10436,10584,10342,10861,11190,10721,11171,10564,10545,94,10087,73,10755,10869,10547,10706,10346,444,426,10059,153,122,10674,64,113,11101,10231,10337,806,11117,10385,251,11188,491,11192,100,10792,10069,10864,11099,10246,10178,10758,10568,10230,10124,10384,10782,10726,384,10670,305,10763,10768,10585,10394,10552,498,10677,1348,168,10814,10582,10382,11093,11173,10381,427,441)) limit 50000;
```

but why do I get an error?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 50' at line 1

What's wrong? And how to limit delete query entries to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

You are better off `SELECT`ing the ids you want to delete with said limit and then deleting those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the syntaxis of [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) if you try to delete with joins, you better create the tables with CASCADE on update.

Comment: You need to alter your tables, so when you delete a parent record, it delete the childen's fields too. Read about [Foreign Keys](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/mysql/mysql_quickguide_foreign_keys.html) or the proper [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) in short words, each table, have a Id from another table, when you delete the record from that table, you set the cascade parameter, and will delete the record in the second table too.