# mysql, delete records from one table 2 that are found in table 1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (unsubscribers und unsubscribers_real)

I want to delete all records in "unsubscribers_real" that are found in "unsubscribers"

example:

table "unsubscribers"

ID,email

1, namex1@domain.com

2, namex2@something.com

3, namex3@domain.com

.

.

table "unsubscribers_real"

ID,email

1, namex1@domain.com

2, namex2@domain.com

3, namex3@domain.com

4, namex4@domain.com

5, namex5@domain.com

so with one MySQL command, deleting
namex1@domain.com, namex3@domain.com
from table unsubscribers_real
(dont delete anything in table1 "unsubscribers")

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql delete in one table by id's from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963746/mysql-delete-in-one-table-by-ids-from-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

An `exists` condition should do the trick:

```sql
DELETE FROM unsubscribers_real ur
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   unsubscirbers u
               WHERE  u.id = ur.id AND u.email = ur.email)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM unsubscribers_real U
    WHERE
        U.email IN (SELECT email FROM unsubscribers )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to delete the rows based on the column `email`.
You need a join in the `DELETE` statement:

```
delete ur
from unsubscribers_real ur inner join unsubscribers u
on u.email = ur.email;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oY4jZUT9bzYQU3nR435ZRL/0).
Results (remaining rows in `unsubscribers_real` ):

```
| ID  | email             |
| --- | ----------------- |
| 2   | namex2@domain.com |
| 4   | namex4@domain.com |
| 5   | namex5@domain.com |
```